# How do I stop a UIActivityIndicator from animating after successfully retrieving/loading from remote JSON?

Tags: ios, swift3, tableview

i've inserted an ActivityIndicator at the UpRight Corner inside the NavigationBar. it starts spinning and my tableview delays a millisecs'or 1 sec getting all data from a json. i need to make it stop when all data is shown on my TableView.

Would anybody help me!? i'm new in this coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create your activity indicator right under your class so it should be accessible in all the functions inside your class

```
var activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()
```

inside viewDidLoad

```
activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
// set the activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopeped to true will hides when you call the stop on activityIndicator
activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = .gray
view.addSubview(activityIndicator)
```

You should have already a block or delegate which informs you that download or parsing of the data has been done right there stop the activity indicator like so

```
activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
```

This will stop the animation also as we had already set the hidesWhenStopped to true it will hide it as well

Comment: Khalid Afridi -----> taking your knowledge as a good lead would you like to help me out with this please... ;http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43332596/how-can-i-show-in-google-map-the-nearest-places-to-my-location

Comment: @SummerRamos I have started my own blog as well I don't have many post but I will be posting some new staff weekly you may have check there as well some times [Swiftyninja](https://swiftyninja.com)