# How can i show in Google Map the nearest places to my location?

Tags: ios, mysql, json, google-maps, swift3

Im trying to create an iOS App, i'm not entirely sure about a few things with swift by now, but i´m still learning every day!

My question is...

How can i show in Google Map the nearest places to my location?! Im getting an array from mysql DB with Latitude & Longitude, but i can't (i have no idea) how to place those selected records in my map! (i mean a determined radius from my location)
would somebody help me please?!

## iOS #MySQL #JSON #GoogleMapsSDK #Swift3

I'm using **AlamoFire** & **Swifty** PODs to work with the arrays

```
    func getDatos(){

    let key = "654321"
    let postString = "buscar=\(self.searchtext)&key=\(key)" //-----------------data send post  ///-------- SEARCH
    let url = URL(string: "http://myWeb.com/myFile.php")!          ///-------- SEARCH
    print(url)
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    
    request.httpMethod = "POST" //-----------sending -> post method
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8) //---------------concatenate my variables with utf8 coding
    
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data else { //---------------if error do exist finish the func
            print("failed request \(String(describing: error))") //---------------mannage the error
            return //------------- break code block
        }
        
        do {//----------- create son object
            
            if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [NSDictionary] {
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async { //-----------------main process
                    for result in json {
                        let id = result["id"] as! String
                        let country = result["country"] as! String
                        let lati = result["lati"] as! String
                        let long = result["long"] as! String
                        
                        self.idCountry.append(id) //--------------------push elements into array
                        self.ctryCountry.append(country)
                        self.latiCountry.append(lati)
                        self.longCountry.append(long)
                    }
                    self.tableView.reloadData() //-------------------reload table again
                }
            }
        
        } catch let parseError { //------------------mannage error
            print("parsing error: \(parseError)")
            
            let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            print("response : \(String(describing: responseString))")
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

There's my func to receive an array with data fields i put into variables, after that i can place it in a tableViewController or show markers with GoogleMapsSDK . The thing is that i have an X number of rows but i just want to show those who are nearby located!!!

Comment: you have to come up with some code because here can be a lot of things going on but a quick suggestion is you have to convert your data from MySQL or JSON to right format first but I don't know what are you trying here at the time

Comment: updated question!